# How to show ancillary statistic of normal random sample?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, ancillary-statistics

Let $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $X_i$ are independent. Then how to show that:
$$
T = \left(\frac{X_1-\bar{X}}{S},\frac{X_2-\bar{X}}{S},\ldots,\frac{X_n-\bar{X}}{S}\right)
$$
$T$ is an ancillary statistic.

Comment: 1/ This seems to be some kind of homework. Is so, please tag it as self-study. 2/ Do you understand what you have to prove? In plain English, it means that observing the value taken by $T$ in a particular experiment does not give information on $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Does this help you?

Comment: It's just self study and not homework, I figured out the solution. I can just say that $X_i$ belongs to a location-scale family and use that transformation to prove the above.

Comment: @A Gore: Then you can answer your own question, so this can get closed ...